# foreach & silencer in a makefile target

Tags: foreach, makefile, silent

I am using a foreach in a makefile for a particular target.

```
my_Target:
    $(foreach x,$(MY_TARGET_DIRS), @echo "  BUILD   $(x)";$(Q)$(MAKE) --directory=$(x) LIB_DIR=$(MY_LIB_DIR) $(MY_TARGET_RULES); )
```

This is intended call the makefiles contained every specified directory of MY_TARGET_DIRS, after a string has been printed to tell which build is ongoing.

The Q variable is defined as follows:

```
# Silent per default, 'make V=1' shows all compiler calls. 
ifneq ($(V),1)
    Q := @
endif
```

So that the make command is verbose if V=1 is defined.

For V=1 the output log is:

```
make my_Target V=1 
BUILD   /dir1
make[1]: Entering directory `/dir1'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `elf'.
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `bin'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/dir1'
/bin/sh: @echo: command not found
make[1]: Entering directory `/dir2'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `elf'.
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `bin'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/dir2'
```

While if I do not define V=1, the output log is:

```
make my_Target 
BUILD   /dir1
/bin/sh: @make: command not found
/bin/sh: @echo: command not found
/bin/sh: @make: command not found
make: *** [my_Target] Error 127
```

How can I get the behavior I desire correctly?

Bye!

Comment: The `@` for quite is a Makefile construct (not a bash one), and _must be at the start of the recipe_.    Bash is choking on the unrecognized symbol.

Comment: You might also look at http://make.mad-scientist.net/managing-recipe-echoing/ for an alternate/better(?) way of handling echo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `@` (`$(Q)`) at the beginning of the recipe:

```
my_Target:
    $(Q)$(foreach x,$(MY_TARGET_DIRS), echo "  BUILD   $(x)";$(MAKE) --directory=$(x) LIB_DIR=$(MY_LIB_DIR) $(MY_TARGET_RULES); )
```

Notice that the `foreach` will ouptut a single recipe line, and the `@` will apply to all of it.   An alternative, if you want to get more fancy is to create a rule for each of the target dirs:

```
MY_TARGET_DIRS_TARGS=$(MY_TARGET_DIRS:%=%/.phony)

my_Target: $(MY_TARGET_DIRS_TARG)

$(MY_TARGET_DIRS_TARGS):
     @echo "  BUILD   $(x)"
     $(Q)(MAKE) --directory=$(x) LIB_DIR=$(MY_LIB_DIR) $(MY_TARGET_RULES);

.PHONY: $(MY_TARGET_DIRS_TARGS)
```

Comment: You didn't take the `$(Q)` out of the `foreach` loop in your first example.

Comment: Oops -- missed that.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I also use the other target that creates a rule for every directory, but with different prerequisites, and I wanted to try using the foreach.